# Selecting elements in matrix using matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, selected

My problem is this: I've a matrix, as example

```
1   2   3 
4   2   6
6   1   8
4   5   4
7   1   5
8   2   0
```

I wish to extract selected values from the matrix, as example, a vector like this

```
B = [3 6 0]
```

selecting third column values when the value in the second column is 2.
I tried in different ways, but no one of these works.

Answer (score 2):

Use this -

```
B = A(A(:,2)==2,3)' %// Assuming A is your input matrix
```

Answer (score 2):

If M is your Matrix, you can select the second column using

```
M(:,2)
```

Compare it to two to get the lines which contain a 2

```
M(:,2)==2
```

And use this logical vector to select your elements from the third column.

```
M(M(:,2)==2,3)
```

Answer (score 1):

A little more generally: if you want to select based on a set of values, use [`ismember`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) to generate the logical index:

```
>> A(ismember(A(:,2), [2 5]) , 3) %// [2 5]: values you want to find in 2nd col

ans =

     3
     4
     6
     0
```

Comment: Maybe you can mention about [1 5] that 1 and 5 are the values in the second column is what one is looking for. Better example could one that involves `2`, so something like [2 5] maybe because OP is looking for `2`?